# StringUtils.substringBetween returns null value

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-stringutils

I've a problem with the following code:

```
public String SearchText(String fileName, String First, String Last) {
        String tag = new String();
        String file = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(fileName));
        tag = StringUtils.substringBetween(file, First, Last);
        return First + tag + Last;
    }
```

It returns me also a "null" value after the string, for example: if I search text between tags `<a>` and `</a>` it returns `<a>null</a>`. The problem is that "tag" as a null value!
The textfile as multiple tags with the same name, each of this including different text: is it possible that the problem is there? And how can I solve it?

Comment: Sidenote: get rid of the initialization of `tag` in the first line of your method, simply write `String tag;`. There's no use in assigning a value if you overwrite it two lines below.

Comment: There's no here the problem, it doesn't change nothing!

Comment: I know that that was not the problem, that's why I said "Sidenote". It was just a general hint regarding code quality.

Comment: Another sidenote: You should stick to the java conventions and camelCase your variables, makes it easier to read for us.

Answer (score 1):

What you say isn't possible. If `SearchText` returns `<a>text</a>null`, then that must mean:

```
First = "<a>";
tag = "text";
Last = "</a>null";
```

which wouldn't find anything. If `StringUtils.substringBetween()` can't find a match, it returns `null` which means `SearchText` would return `<a>null</a>null`. With the code above, the only way to get `<a>text</a>null` is:

```
First = "<a>text</a>";
Last = "";
```

So what you say in your question isn't possible. Check the content of all variables again, something is not as you say.

Comment: Exactly, and I want to remove "null" but I don't know how.

Comment: In that case, you should show us the code which calls the method above.

Comment: Excuse me, it's First that contains null. The code it's a simple call in the main.

Comment: If `First` contained `null`, the code above would return `nulltext</a>`. There is something wrong with the information that you're giving us. Please make sure that `First`, `Last` and `file` contain what you expect.

Comment: The problem is that "tag" as a null value! The textfile as multiple tags with the same name, each of this including different text: is it possible that the problem is there?